# Update the first matching record only without duplicating records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have records in a table A (first name, last name, Tags) and the tags column is Null and records on this columns will be duplicated the same first name and last name

```
Table A
{     
first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’’,
first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’’,
first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’’,
first name =’Ibrahim’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’’
}
```

And I have another table A with exact same columns, more records than table A and all records have Tags and also the records can be duplicated.

```
Table B
{ 
first name =’Mostafa’, Last name =’hamza’, Tag=’3245435’,
first name =’Ayman’, Last name =’Malek’, Tag=’45455’,
first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’12345’,
first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’87654’,
first name =’Ibrahim’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’658568’
}
```

I want to update the Tags on table A depending on the corresponding value on table B and Only I can find unique tags on table A.

The issues is when I try to update with update statement and where the last tag on table B matches the criteria is always updating the whole matching records in table A, so mapping is not correct like the below:

```
  Table A
    { 
    first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’87654’,
    first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’87654’,
    first name =’Ibrahim’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’658568’
    }
```

and the desired output should be:

```
  Table A
    { 
    first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’12345’,
    first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’87654’,
    first name =’Mohamed’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’’,
    first name =’Ibrahim’, Last name =’Ahmed’, Tag=’658568’
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual desired final output?

Comment: I had modified the question of the wrong result and expected result

Comment: You shouldn't change your question after accepting an answer, because it invalidates all the work others have already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a row number to both tables in a CTE, and then do an update join:

```
WITH cteA AS (
    SELECT [first name], [Last name], Tag,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [first name], [Last name] ORDER BY Tag) rn
    FROM tableA
),
cteB AS (
    SELECT [first name], [Last name], Tag,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [first name], [Last name] ORDER BY Tag) rn
    FROM tableA
)

UPDATE a
SET Tag = b.Tag
FROM cteA a
INNER JOIN cteB b
    ON a.[first name] = b.[first name] AND
       a.[Last name] = b.[Last name] AND
       a.rn = b.rn;
```

The trick here is that each record in a first name/last name group gets assigned a row number. For table A, the assignment of row number is not meaningful, since there are no tags, but in your example one of the two records would be assigned 1 and the other 2. For table B, the assignment of row number would depend on the ordering of the tag. Again, this ordering may not matter, but combining these two row numbers gives us a way to ensure that each record in table B will logically map to only a single record in table A.

Comment: LOL, just posted the same answer after 5 second of yours :P

Comment: @Nitin_g3 It's OK...leave yours up, maybe I missed something

Comment: Nah, I'm gonna get rid of it.